# Calculate average in NodeJS from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, average

I have a script which is taking data from [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) every 30 minute interval and shows it in terminal.
I would like to calculate the average for every asset which I have in array.

This is [Node-Schedule package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) -  `const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *'`

Small example: `var array = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC", "AIONBTC"]`
I want to calculate separate average for `"ADABTC"`, for `"AEBTC"` and for `"KAVABTC"`.

**Full Code**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const symbols = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC", "AIONBTC", "ALGOBTC", "ARDRBTC", "ARKBTC", "ATOMTC"]

const getBTCData = async symbol => { 
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Volume: parseInt(d[5]),
            Timespan: 30,
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
};

const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', async() => {
    for (let symbol of symbols) {
        await getBTCData(symbol);
        await sleep(4000);
    }
});
```

Goal: How I can calculate the average of Volume which is this part - `Volume: parseInt(d[5]),` for every asset if I will receive them every 30 minute?

Comment: This API will give us a number of stats for the given symbol (and interval), such as Open, High, Low, Close etc. Do you wish to determine the average price for that single data point? or do you wish to get the price every 30 minutes, then average these prices, say for the day?

Comment: @TerryLennox Hello! I want to calculate average for volume, that's why I have 'parseInt(d[5]). I will update my question to be more correct in it. I want to get average of Volume of every asset and then make an average of upcoming ones. Like after 2 hours of script working I have 4 numbers for every asset and I want to calculate average of this 4 numbers for every asset.

Comment: Ah yes, very good. Thanks for the detailed update!

Comment: @TerryLennox Looking forward for any suggestion on how I can make it. Thanks for reviewing

Comment: @TerryLennox If you will find a time I would like to maybe have a chat with you personally, according to your SO profile I think you can bring me some light on nodejs back-end system at all. But I really wish that we can get through my first question first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of collecting averages (and other stats) would be to create a map keyed by symbol.

We would keep a history for each symbol, then compute an average for, say, volume each time we get a new data point.

An example might look like so (I've updated the call frequency to once every 10 seconds for demo purposes!)

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const symbols = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC", "AIONBTC", "ALGOBTC", "ARDRBTC", "ARKBTC", ]

const symbolSummary = {};

const getBTCData = async symbol => { 
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Volume: parseInt(d[5]),
            Timespan: 30,
            symbol
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
    return btcusdtdata;
};

const appendBTCDataToSummary = (btcData, summary) => {
    if (!summary[btcData.symbol]) {
        summary[btcData.symbol] = { history: [], symbol: btcData.symbol };
    }
    let symbolHistory = summary[btcData.symbol].history;
    symbolHistory.push(btcData);
    summary[btcData.symbol].averageVolume = symbolHistory.reduce((average, row) => {
        // Calculate the average volume by scaling each volume entry by 1 / length.
        return average + (row.Volume) * (1 / symbolHistory.length);
    }, 0)
    summary[btcData.symbol].dataPoints = symbolHistory.length;
}

const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', async() => {
    for (let symbol of symbols) {
        let btcData = await getBTCData(symbol);
        appendBTCDataToSummary(btcData[0], symbolSummary);
        // We must back off between calls as per api terms of use.
        await sleep(4000);
    }

    console.log("Symbol summaries:", Object.values(symbolSummary).map(summary => { 
        return { symbol: summary.symbol, AverageVolume: summary.averageVolume, DataPoints: summary.dataPoints };
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I will test it out today to see how it works and I will get back for you! Super appreciate !

Comment: On a first look and on my test it looks sharp a hell. Working fine without any problem at all. Just one mark which I want to point is missing of 'await sleep(4000) or at least (2000). Explaining : In Binance API writed that there suppose to be delay of at least 2 seconds otherwise you can receive an IP ban for maximum of 72 hours. I'm just pointing this up for another people who will use the code for their purposes. On other note it works perfectly. Definitely like and upvote. Thank you sir, really appreciated!

Comment: Ah  yes, I see. That makes sense. I'll add back in the sleep call, this is basically a requirement if we don't want a ban!

Comment: hey is it possible to have a chat with you?

Comment: Sure.. I created a chat here..https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217864/room-for-terry-lennox-and-hexycode

Comment: If you have time, there is bounty on my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953812/calculating-the-average-for-last-200-days-in-mongodb-aggregation-and-nodejs/62953991?noredirect=1#comment111330065_62953991

Comment: @Hexycode Can you please point to the docs where it is explained about that 2 seconds restriction. I didn't noticed that nowhere hah...