# Calculating the average for last 200 days in MongoDB aggregation and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a script which is calculating the average `Volume` data for every collection in my MongoDB. But since I have more that a 1000 days in record I wish to calculate the `Average Volume` only for last 200 days.

Currently my script taking the whole data which is in collection (1000days+).

Goal: How I can setup a range of last 200 days to calculate the average `Volume` for them. Also pretty important thing that every next day I still want to use only last 200 days.

**Average aggregation Framework**

```
const saveToDatebase = async(symbol, BTCdata) => {
    try {
        const url = 'mongodb://username:passwprd@ipaddress/port?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
        let dateTime = getDateTime();
        let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);
        await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
        const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{
            '$group': {
            _id:null,
                'Volume': {
                    '$avg': '$Volume'
                }
            }
        }]).toArray();
        console.log('1 document inserted');
        console.log(average);
        db.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
};
```

**EDIT1**
After editing the code like this >>

```
const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $gte: ["$dateTime", { $subtract: ["$$NOW", 200 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000] }]
    },
    "$group": {
        _id: null,
        "Volume": {
            "$avg": "$Volume"
        }
    }
}]).toArray();
```

I receive this error > `MongoError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`

**EDIT2**
**Code** After having code like below I receive this error - `MongoError: unknown top level operator: $gte`

```
const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{
                $match: { $gte: ["$dateTime", { $subtract: ["$$NOW", 200 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000] }] }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    _id: null,
                    "Volume": {
                        "$avg": "$Volume"
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

Here is how document looks like in MongoDB.

[image]

**EDIT3**
Here is how my code looks like regarding the last improvement. Code is working the only problem It didn't return me average. In my terminal I receive an empty array `[]` but I don't receive any error. I'm thinking that the problem is here - `"$dateTime"` I think the query for it is wrong. Cause I'm also trying to make it in MongoDB Compass. Doesn't work as well.

**Code Here**

```
  const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $gte: [
                        "$dateTime",
                        {
                            $subtract: [
                                "$$NOW",
                                200 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                _id: null,
                "Volume": {
                    "$avg": "$Volume"
                }
            }
        }
    ]).toArray();
```

**EDIT4**

The only problem now that I receive an empty array > `[]` I receive an empty array cause the `Date` is saving as `string` to MongoDB but to make aggregation framework work I need to store it as `object`.

In code below there is my way of creating Date function it saves it in MongoDB as `string` how I can change it to save it as `object`

```
const getDateTime = () => {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return date + ' ' + time;
};

const saveToDatebase = async(symbol, BTCdata) => {
    try {
        const url = 'mongodb://username:password@ipadress/port?dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
        let dateTime = getDateTime();
        let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);
        await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
        const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{
                '$match': {
                    'dateTime': { '$gte': new Date((new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) }
                },
            },
            {
                '$group': {
                    _id: null,
                    'Volume': { '$avg': '$Volume' }
                },
            }
        ]).toArray();
        console.log('1 document inserted');
        console.log(average);
        db.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
};
```

Document from MongoDB as text:

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f158c9d80d84408f6c38d8b"
    },
    "Name": "ADABTC",
    "Date": "2020-7-20 13:22:53",
    "Open": 0.0000133,
    "High": 0.0000133,
    "Low": 0.00001325,
    "Close": 0.00001326,
    "Volume": 1189734,
    "Timespan": 30
}
```

Comment: Is your `Date` attribute a **String** (=very bad) or a `Date` object (as it should be)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes it's a string.

Comment: const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);

This is how it looks like, any ideas on how I can change it into object instead of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter documents before you group them. Should be like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         DateObj: {
            $regexFindAll: { input: "$Date", regex: "\\d+" }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         DateObj: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 0] } },
               month: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 1] } },
               day: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 2] } },
               hour: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 3] } },
               minute: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 4] } },
               second: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 5] } },
               timezone: "Europe/Zurich"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $gte: ["$DateObj", { $subtract: ["$$NOW", 200 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000] }]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$group": {
         _id: null,
         "Volume": {
            "$avg": "$Volume"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: @WenfriedDomscheit I think there is some typo mistake cause one bracket show error. Still thank you for answer! Going to test it now

Comment: After editing the code your way I receive this error - MongoError: unknown top level operator: $gte

Comment: @WenfriedDomscheit Hello again! I test your answer, it works, but it doesn't show average - In terminal I receive any empty array > [] No error messages. Going to update my question accordingly

Comment: Please provide sample documents as formatted text instead of an image

Comment: Probably the problem is that I'm saving the Date as string but it's supposed to be an object. Currently I stuck with how I can save Date in MongoDB as object not like string

Comment: Provide what you have, I will give the conversion

Comment: @WenfriedDomscheit Check the edit in main question. Just updated it

Comment: That is not a sample document

Comment: Edited the main question, added the document as formatted text

Comment: Please see my updated answer. As you see, you should really try to use proper `Date` object, the conversion from string is not that simple.

Comment: It works, I'll confirm it as correct answer and I can award bounty only after 19 hours